# What is the difference between Date and last modified in S3 bucket item?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

[image]

I am trying to figure out the difference Last Modified and Date in headers of an S3 item.
Looks like Date was when the request was made and last modified was when it got created on S3.Am I reading it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Correct, `Date` is the timestamp of the [response to your query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html):

> The date and time Amazon S3 responded

And `Last-Modified` is the timestamp of, well, the [last modification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingMetadata.html):

> Object creation date or the last modified date, whichever is the latest.